# How to change the appearance of a card in Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to modify the appearance of cards created in a google glass application developed using the GDK. I've found the right place to modify the appearance - styles.xml. Here's the current code that gives me a glass-styled card:

```
<style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

</style>
```

Whenever I add anything in between those lines, though, the appearance of the cards never changes. But when I change the parent of the theme to one of the default Android themes, I can alter the appearance no problem (but the status bar is at the top, so I can't just use that instead of the glass theme). I really just want to center the text in my app - is there a way to do this? Am I looking at the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Card class to create your cards you basically have 3 options:

1. No image, text will be by default at the upper left corner.
2. If you use an image with FULL layout, text will be somewhere at the bottom, and will be left aligned.
3. If you use an image with LEFT layout, text will be again at top left aligned.

You can use the android textview instead of card and can then inflate your own XML to the view.